# Exception Handling in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, exception, spring-boot, http-request-parameters

I have a spring-boot application which has the following end point:

```
@RequestMapping("/my-end-point")
public MyCustomObject handleProduct(
  @RequestParam(name = "productId") String productId,
  @RequestParam(name = "maxVersions", defaultValue = "1") int maxVersions,
){
   // my code
}
```

This should handle requests of the form

```
/my-end-point?productId=xyz123&maxVersions=4
```

However, when I specify `maxVersions=3.5`, this throws `NumberFormatException` (for obvious reason). How can I gracefully handle this `NumberFormatException` and return an error message?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can define an `ExceptionHandler` in the same controller or in a `ControllerAdvice` that handles the `MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException` exception:

```
@ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException.class)
public void handleTypeMismatch(MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException ex) {
    String name = ex.getName();
    String type = ex.getRequiredType().getSimpleName();
    Object value = ex.getValue();
    String message = String.format("'%s' should be a valid '%s' and '%s' isn't", 
                                   name, type, value);

    System.out.println(message);
    // Do the graceful handling
}
```

If during controller method argument resolution, Spring detects a type mismatch between the method argument type and actual value type, it would raise an `MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException`. For more details on how to define an `ExceptionHandler`, you can consult the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-exceptionhandler).